# Passing 2D Arrays with Pointers (C)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, 2d

Below is the code I am working with. This works perfectly fine when I run it and comment out the code dealing with the `addArray`s function.

I believe I am not using the pointers properly in the `addArrays` function. Any help will be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void addArrays(int rowSize, int columnSize, int Array1[rowSize][columnSize],
               int Array2[rowSize][columnSize],
               int *sumloc[rowSize][columnSize]);
void printArray(int rowSize, int columnSize, int arrayValue[rowSize][columnSize]);

/*
This program will make 2 2D matrices out of a random number of rows, 3 columns, and a random set of values.
Then, the two matrices will be added and all three printed.
*/

int main() {
    //To get a true random number
    srand(time(NULL));

    int rowSize = rand() % 4 + 1;
    int columnSize = 2;
    int Array1[rowSize][columnSize];
    int Array2[rowSize][columnSize];
    int Arraysum[rowSize][columnSize];

    //For loop counter
    int col;
    int row;

    //Makes a unique number for each part of both arrays from 0-50
    for (row = 0; row <= rowSize; row++)
        for (col = 0; col <= columnSize; col++)
            Array1[row][col] = rand() % 50;

    for (row = 0; row <= rowSize; row++)
        for (col = 0; col <= columnSize; col++)
            Array2[row][col] = rand() % 50;


    //Add arrays
    addArrays(rowSize, columnSize, Array1[rowSize][columnSize],
              Array2[rowSize][columnSize],v&Arraysum[rowSize][columnSize]);

    //Utilizes the print function
    printArray(rowSize, columnSize, Array1);
    printArray(rowSize, columnSize, Array2);
    printArray(rowSize, columnSize, &Arraysum);

    return 0;
}

void addArrays(int rowSize, int columnSize, int a1[rowSize][columnSize],
               int a2[rowSize][columnSize],
               int *sumloc[rowSize][columnSize]) {
    int row;
    int col;
    sumloc[rowSize][columnSize] = malloc(rowSize * columnSize * sizeof(int));

    for (row = 0; row <= rowSize; row++)
        for (col = 0; col <= columnSize; col++)
            *sumloc[row][col] = a1[row][col] + a2[row][col];

    return;
}

void printArray(int rowSize, int columnSize, int arrayValue[rowSize][columnSize]) {
    int row;
    int col;

    for (row = 0; row <= rowSize; row++) {
        printf("\n");
        printf("[");
        for (col = 0; col <= columnSize; col++) {
            printf(" %d ", arrayValue[row][col]);
        }
        printf("]");
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    return;
}
```

Comment: You didn't say anything about what error you get (compile? runtime? What message?) You're calling the function wrong. You're calling it using the declarations. The type is already `int[][]`, so just pass the name: `addArrays(rowSize, columnSize,  Array1, Array2, &Arraysum);`. You might also want to consider more sensible names for your arrays.

Comment: All these `<=` operators seem incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several issues:

- You should not use `<=` in your `for` loops, you access elements beyond the end of the arrays.
- The number of rows and columns are of by one.
- You should pass the arrays directly instead of passing the array elements or tentatively passing the address of the destination array.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void addArrays(int rowSize, int columnSize, int Array1[rowSize][columnSize],
               int Array2[rowSize][columnSize],
               int Result[rowSize][columnSize]);
void printArray(int rowSize, int columnSize, int arrayValue[rowSize][columnSize]);

/*
This program will make 2 2D matrices out of a random number of rows
and 3 columns, and a random set of values.
Then, the two matrices will be added and all three printed.
*/

int main() {
    //To get a pseudo random number
    srand(time(NULL));

    int rowSize = rand() % 4 + 1;  // number between 1 and 4
    int columnSize = 3;
    int Array1[rowSize][columnSize];
    int Array2[rowSize][columnSize];
    int Arraysum[rowSize][columnSize];

    //Makes a unique number for each part of both arrays from 0-50
    for (int row = 0; row < rowSize; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < columnSize; col++) {
            Array1[row][col] = rand() % 50;
            Array2[row][col] = rand() % 50;
        }
    }

    //Add matrices
    addArrays(rowSize, columnSize, Array1, Array2, Arraysum);

    //Utilizes the print function
    printArray(rowSize, columnSize, Array1);
    printArray(rowSize, columnSize, Array2);
    printArray(rowSize, columnSize, Arraysum);
    return 0;
}

void addArrays(int rowSize, int columnSize, int a1[rowSize][columnSize],
               int a2[rowSize][columnSize], int result[rowSize][columnSize]) {
    for (int row = 0; row < rowSize; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < columnSize; col++)
            result[row][col] = a1[row][col] + a2[row][col];
    }
}

void printArray(int rowSize, int columnSize, int array[rowSize][columnSize]) {
    for (int row = 0; row < rowSize; row++) {
        printf("\n");
        printf("[");
        for (int col = 0; col < columnSize; col++) {
            printf(" %d ", array[row][col]);
        }
        printf("]");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you for finding this. This was actually half my problem. I'm still new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `addArrays(..)` function:

```
void addArrays(int rowSize, int columnSize, int a1[rowSize][columnSize], int a2[rowSize][columnSize], int sumloc[rowSize][columnSize]) {

int row;
int col;

for(row = 0; row <= rowSize; row++)
    for(col = 0; col <= columnSize; col++)
        sumloc[row][col] = a1[row][col] + a2[row][col];

return;
}
```

You don't need the `*` at `sumloc` in your function prototype, and you don't have to allocate any more memory for it.

Answer (score 0):

**TL/DR Version**

You don't need to muck with pointers (directly) in this code at all; just call the `addArrays` function as

```
addArrays(rowSize, columnSize, Array1, Array2 ,Arraysum);
```

and change the declaration/definition to

```
void addArrays(int rowSize, int columnSize, int Array1[rowSize][columnSize],
           int Array2[rowSize][columnSize],
           int sumloc[rowSize][columnSize])
```

lose the call to `malloc` completely, and lose the `*` operator from any references to `sumloc`:

```
sumloc[row][col] = a1[row][col] + a2[row][col];
```

Similarly, change the call to `printArray` to

```
printArray(rowSize, columnSize, Arraysum);
```

**Slightly Longer Version**

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize another array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

Your first set of issues are in the function call:

```
addArrays(rowSize, columnSize, Array1[rowSize][columnSize],
          Array2[rowSize][columnSize],&Arraysum[rowSize][columnSize]);
```

First of all, you're not passing the *arrays* as parameters in this call; you're passing a *single element* of `Array1` and `Array2` and a pointer to a single element of `Arraysum`, and all of these elements are past the end of their respective arrays (remember that an `N`-element array is indexed from `0` to `N-1`, so the last element of each array would be at index `[rowSize-1][columnSize-1]`).

What you want to pass are the *array expressions*, not single elements, like so:

```
addArrays( rowSize, columnSize, Array1, Array2, Arraysum );
```

Since the three array expressions are *not* the operands of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, their types will be converted from "`N`-element array of `T`" to "pointer to `T`".  In this case, `N` is `rowSize` and `T` is "`columnSize`-element array of `int`".  Thus, what the function *actually receives* are three parameters of type `int (*)[columnSize]`.

Also, in the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are equivalent to `T *a`<sup>1</sup>; all three declare `a` as a pointer to `T`, not as an array of `T`<sup>2</sup>.

That means

```
void addArrays( int rowSize, int columnSize, int Array1[rowSize][columnSize],
  int Array2[rowSize][columnSize], int sumloc[rowSize][columnSize])
```

could be written as

```
void addArrays( int rowSize, int columnSize, int Array1[][columnSize],
  int Array2[][columnSize], int sumloc[][columnSize])
```

or

```
void addArrays( int rowSize, int columnSize, int (*Array1)[columnSize],
  int (*Array2)[columnSize], int (*sumloc)[columnSize] )
```

Regardless of the form of declaration, you'd still access each array expression as a regular 2D array (`sumloc[i][j] = Array1[i][j] + Array2[i][j];`).

Note that since you're actually passing *pointers*, any changes made to the arrays in the `addArray` function are reflected in the caller (`main`).  This is why you don't need to use the `&` operator for the `Arraysum` parameter (and note that the type of the expression `&Arraysum` is `int (*)[rowSize][columnSize]` - that is, a pointer to a `rowSize` by `columnSize` array of `int).  While the expressions`Arraysum`and`&Arraysum` yield the same *value* (the address of an array is the same as the address of the first element of the array), the *types* of the two expressions are different, and types matter.

---

<sup>1.  The equivalence of `T a[]` and `T *a` in a function parameter declaration is a holdover from the B programming language, from which C was derived.  In B, a pointer variable was declared using empty square brackets like `auto p[]`.  Personally, I think keeping an alternative form of pointer declaration that's only valid in one context is a mistake, but I'm not a language designer.

2.  This is *only* true for function parameter declarations, not regular declarations.</sup>